# how can i make a KB from the DB in Genexus

Tags: genexus

I'm programming in Genexus and I need to create a Knowledge Base from a data base that I already own, I only see how to create a database from a knowlegde base.

Answer (score 4):

To import the database structure to Knowledge Base, you must use Tools / Database Reverse Engineering and follow the wizard.

To create a Knowledge Base, from a Knowledge Database (MDF file) you must use Open   / Knowledge Base / (select Knowledge Base DB ) in combo.